# Openshift MySQL Connector

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, openshift, mysql-connector

I'm encountering the following error when trying to connect to the database:

**java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/** etc.

The MySQL connector .jar is inside the WEB-INF/lib folder

The following as been added to the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.32</version>
</dependency>
```

Any assistance / guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling the driver class?:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

an example is shown below.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    // error out
}
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(/*your connection query*/);
```

Comment: Yes the driver class was called, though I don't believe it is always necessary to do so. The problem seems to be with getting the connector .jar in the projects classpath.

Comment: @FishSaidNo It initialize the class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" if found in the classpath, this imply that the driver is registered in the JDBC driver manager since the registration process is inside the static initializer of the driver class